# Normal form submitting correctly but ajax form submits null

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, forms

I have developed a super simple REST API in Flask using Flask-RESTful for development purposes. It takes text from a POST method and returns json data with the submitted text.

The code for the API:

#### api.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
CORS(app)


class APITest(Resource):

    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument('text')

    def get(self):
        return {'message': 'welcome to the api!'}

    def post(self):

        args = self.parser.parse_args()
        _text = args['text']

        return {'text': _text}


api.add_resource(APITest, '/api')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now, the following HTML works completely fine and I get the response I'm looking for with no errors:

#### index.html

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:5000/api">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text-input">
    <input type="submit" value="Send!">
</form>
```

> returns: `{ 'text': 'whatever text i submitted' }`

If I try to do the exact same thing, but with AJAX, I get a different result:

#### index.html

```
...
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="submit.js"</script>
...

<form>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text-input">
    <input type="submit" value="Send!">
</form>
```

#### submit.js

```
$("form").submit((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  var fd = new FormData()
  fd.append('text', $('#text-input').val())

  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:5000/api',
      type: 'POST',
      data: fd,
      processData: false
  });

  return false;
})
```

> returns `{'text': null}`

#### Things I've tried

- replacing `${'text-input').val()` with `document.getElementById('text-input').value`
- various different ways of sending "form data" including `var fd = { text: ${'text-input').val() }`

Comment: Can you verify data is being sent from the form to the backend when using ajax?  Perhaps you're not sending anything.

Comment: @Jhorra I added `success: function (x) { console.log(x) },` to the ajax form and got back `Object {text: null}` in my console.

Comment: Also, my Flask API log is also logging `127.0.0.1 - - [25/Dec/2016 18:18:01] "POST /api HTTP/1.1" 200 -` every time I submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try is just grabbing the form data using jquery rather than building it yourself.  Example:

```
<form id="respond_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text-input">
    <input type="file" name="fl" id="fl">
    <input type="submit" value="Send!">
</form>

$("#respond_form").submit((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  var form_data = new FormData();  
  var file_data = $("#fl").prop("files")[0]; 
  form_data.append("file", file_data)
  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:5000/api',
      type: 'POST',
      data: form_data,
      processData: false
  });

  return false;
})
```

Comment: That worked! However, does this transfer to a file input? This is a test api, but the one I'm developing handles files, not text.

Comment: @JakeRieger  I've modified it to work with a file.  Serialize won't pull in files.

Comment: I found that the problem with it not receiving files was on the API end, so your code works as expected. Thanks for the help